# how to get data from color band in colorbar?

Tags: matlab

I created a pcolor plot of gridded data, I have colorbar for z data for this data. I would like to determine the threshold from color band in color bar. I am using jet as color map, so i need to extract z value which corresponds to light orange band in the color bar. I would need to extract based on color since the z values wont be consistent with different data set.

Here is the code and the image:

```
figure;
contourf(xC(1,:),yC(:,1),zDiff, 200,'LineColor','none');
colormap('jet');
colorbar;
axis equal
caxis([minmax(zDiff)]);
```

[image]